# ping: unknown host

Tags: rhel

I am setting up a workstation with RHEL 6.6. When I do

```
ping server1
```

it said `ping: unknown host server1`. However I can `ping` server1 with IP address xx.xx.xx.xxx.

It seems to me `/etc/resolv.conf` will be rewritten by NetworkManager.

I do add these in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DNS1=xx.xx.xx.xxx
DNS2=xx.xx.xx.xxx
DOMAIN=xxx.xxx.xx
```

Any suggestion what might went wrong?

Comment: Can you ping the DNS server IP address(es) you put into the `ifcfg-eth0` files?

Answer (score 1):

is server1 a placeholder for an internet site like, say, www.google.com?  Or is it a machine you control on your local network?

If it is your own machine, your DNS probably does not know about it.  You can get it to resolve via adding a line in your hosts file.

If it's a local machine, your options are:

1. add it to every machine's hosts file (these are also available on Windows and OSX hosts) - easiest, but time consuming
2. have the machine IPs handed out (perhaps by MAC id) via a DHCP server that also handles DNS and will serve those names - this is unlikely.  This depends on your DHCP server but, for instance, DD-WRT firmware can do this.
3. run your own DNS server (perhaps using cache DNS) and define your server IPs in the config

example of setting up cache DNS on an Ubuntu server is here, not sure for Red Hat EL.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Create this entry in /etc/hosts file:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server1

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP of server1.

Also, if server1 has public DNS, make sure your /etc/resolv.conf points to 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.2:

cat /etc/resolv.conf:

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 4.2.2.2

If you do not know the public resolution of server1, then find the private resolution of server1 on your network. If there is no private or public resolution, server1 exists only in your imagination but you can still use the /etc/hosts file to make it real for your local machine.